# Incorrect access DOM in setInterval()

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to realize the color flashing effect as below. I use `setInterval()` and I want to reset the color for all grids at the top of function `colorChange()` by using `getElementsByClassName()` and set is as original color, but this statement is not working.[image: Here is my screenshot.]

1. Before I add statement

`document.getElementsByClassName("div").style.enableBackground = "darkorange";`

, the function `colorChange()` works.

2. I tried to use `getElementsById` to access div elements but still not working.
3. I tried to debug in Chrome, the errors shows on the top, but I can't read or find the details. How should I get these information in Chrome?
4. I use `.sort(function(){return 0.5-Math.random()})` method to get random div(s), but actually it's seems like this is not a completely random. How should I improve the code?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JS task flashing s</title>
        <style>
            .div
            {
                padding: 13%;
                border-radius: 3%;
                margin: 1%;
                float: left;
                background-color: darkorange;
            }
            
            
            .main
            {
                width: 80%;
                padding-bottom: 90%;
                border-style:dashed;
            }
            button
            {
                width: 82%;
                padding: 3% 0% 3% 0%;
                margin: 1%;
                background-color: white;
                border-color: darkorange;
                color: darkorange;
            }
            button:hover{
                background-color: darkorange;
                color: white;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="div" id="div1"></div>
            <div class="div" id="div2"></div>
            <div class="div" id="div3"></div>
            <div class="div" id="div4"></div>
            <div class="div" id="div5"></div>
            <div class="div" id="div6"></div>
            <div class="div" id="div7"></div>
            <div class="div" id="div8"></div>
            <div class="div" id="div9"></div>
            <button id="start">Start flashing</button>
            <button id="stop">Stop</button>
        </div>
        

        
        <script>
            var intervalTrigger;
            
 
             document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click",function(){            
                intervalTrigger = setInterval(function colorChange(){ 
                   
                    
                
                function getColor(){
                    r=Math.floor(Math.random()*256);
                    g=Math.floor(Math.random()*256);
                    b=Math.floor(Math.random()*256);
                    return "rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+")";
                }
                
                
            var getId = Array("div1","div2","div3","div4","div5","div6","div7","div8","div9");
            getId.sort(
                function(){
                    return 0.5-Math.random()
                }
            )
                   document.getElementsByClassName("div").style.enableBackground = "darkorange";//Reset blackground color
                document.getElementById(getId[0]).style.backgroundColor = getColor();
               document.getElementById(getId[1]).style.backgroundColor = getColor();
                document.getElementById(getId[2]).style.backgroundColor = getColor();
                

            } ,1000)}
           );
            document.getElementById("stop").addEventListener("click",function(){
                clearInterval(intervalTrigger);
            });
            
            
            
            
            
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName("div")` will return an array of elements. if you use `.style` on array, you will get error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting an EDIT of my older answer here for the sake of clarity. I have rewritten the logic to be better in line with best practices.

```js
var intervalTrigger = null;
var startButton = document.getElementById("start");
var stopButton = document.getElementById("stop");
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('tile');
function getColor() {
  r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  return "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
}

function getRandomArray(divCount){
  var vals = [];
  while(vals.length < 3){
    var val = Math.floor(Math.random() * divCount);
    if(vals.indexOf(val)<0){
      vals.push(val);
    }
  }
  return vals;
}
function handleTick(){
  var divCount = divs.length;
  
  var randomDivs = getRandomArray(divCount);
  
  for(var i = 0; i < divCount; i++){
    if( randomDivs.indexOf(i) > -1){
      divs[i].style.backgroundColor = getColor();
    }else{
      divs[i].style.backgroundColor = 'darkorange';
    }
  }
  
}

function startFlash() {
  if (intervalTrigger) {
    stopFlash();
  }
  intervalTrigger = setInterval(handleTick, 1000);
}

function stopFlash() {
  clearInterval(intervalTrigger);
  intervalTrigger = null;
  for(var i = 0 ; i < divs.length ; i++){
    divs[i].style.backgroundColor = 'darkorange';
  }
}


stopButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  stopFlash();
});
startButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  startFlash();
})
```

```css
.tile {
  padding: 13%;
  border-radius: 3%;
  margin: 1%;
  float: left;
  background-color: darkorange;
}

.main {
  width: 80%;
  border-style: dashed;
}

button {
  width: 82%;
  padding: 3% 0% 3% 0%;
  margin: 1%;
  background-color: white;
  border-color: darkorange;
  color: darkorange;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: darkorange;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <button id="start">Start flashing</button>
  <button id="stop">Stop</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Chirag, could you please let me know: 1, Why assignment null to intervalTrigger? 2, You pick randomDivs with 3 Math.floor(Math.random() * divCount) statements, but this may cause repetition(I want to avoid this situation), is there a way to solve it? 3, There is an "if" statement in startflash, is that for restart when interval loop is executing? Thank you for the answer sincerely.

Comment: For points 1 and 3: We assign that variable to null when the loop is stopped. This is checked for in startFlash so that multiple intervals are not created if the start button is pressed multiple times.
For point 2, when you say it repeats, so you mean that sometimes 2 of the three are the same? Or are you taking about repetitions over time?

Comment: "repeats" means sometimes randomDivs picks same element. This happens when Math.floor(Math.random() * divCount) returns same number, so I use "getId" array instead of Math.random() in my code.

Comment: Ah. Got it. Edited my answer to ensure that the random values generated are distinct

Answer (score 0):

The problem is mostly with this line:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("div").style.enableBackground = "darkorange";
```

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns a list of nodes. You will need to process each of them in a loop and set the background color as needed.

```js
var intervalTrigger;


document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", function() {
  intervalTrigger = setInterval(function colorChange() {



    function getColor() {
      r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
      g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
      b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
      return "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
    }


    var getId = Array("div1", "div2", "div3", "div4", "div5", "div6", "div7", "div8", "div9");
    getId.sort(
      function() {
        return 0.5 - Math.random()
      }
    )
    var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("div");
    for(var i = 0 ; i< divs.length ; i++){
      divs[i].style.backgroundColor = "darkorange"; //Reset blackground color
    }
    document.getElementById(getId[0]).style.backgroundColor = getColor();
    document.getElementById(getId[1]).style.backgroundColor = getColor();
    document.getElementById(getId[2]).style.backgroundColor = getColor();


  }, 1000)
});
document.getElementById("stop").addEventListener("click", function() {
  clearInterval(intervalTrigger);
});
```

```css
.div {
  padding: 13%;
  border-radius: 3%;
  margin: 1%;
  float: left;
  background-color: darkorange;
}

.main {
  width: 80%;
  padding-bottom: 90%;
  border-style: dashed;
}

button {
  width: 82%;
  padding: 3% 0% 3% 0%;
  margin: 1%;
  background-color: white;
  border-color: darkorange;
  color: darkorange;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: darkorange;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="div" id="div1"></div>
  <div class="div" id="div2"></div>
  <div class="div" id="div3"></div>
  <div class="div" id="div4"></div>
  <div class="div" id="div5"></div>
  <div class="div" id="div6"></div>
  <div class="div" id="div7"></div>
  <div class="div" id="div8"></div>
  <div class="div" id="div9"></div>
  <button id="start">Start flashing</button>
  <button id="stop">Stop</button>
</div>
```

EDIT:

Although the above works, a lot of common bad practices are being used (use of `Array` constructor, repeated DOM queries etc). Look at my other answer for another way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Though lot of optimization is required in your code.
Here is working version of it.

I have updated following things.

1. Class name should not be `div`, I have updated it to box
2. `getElementsByClassName` returns list so you need to loop through list to reset background color
3. There is nothing called `enableBackground`
4. `getColor` should be out of interval loop
5. Correct Indentation

```js
var intervalTrigger;
document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", function() {
  intervalTrigger = setInterval(function colorChange() {
    var getId = Array("div1", "div2", "div3", "div4", "div5", "div6", "div7", "div8", "div9");
    getId.sort(
      function() {
        return 0.5 - Math.random()
      }
    )
    var allBox = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

    for (var i = 0; i < allBox.length; i++) {
      allBox[i].style.backgroundColor = "darkorange";
    }

    document.getElementById(getId[0]).style.backgroundColor = getColor();
    document.getElementById(getId[1]).style.backgroundColor = getColor();
    document.getElementById(getId[2]).style.backgroundColor = getColor();
  }, 1000)
});

document.getElementById("stop").addEventListener("click", function() {
  clearInterval(intervalTrigger);
});

function getColor() {
  r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  return "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
}
```

```css
.box {
  padding: 13%;
  border-radius: 3%;
  margin: 1%;
  float: left;
  background-color: darkorange;
}

.main {
  width: 80%;
  padding-bottom: 90%;
  border-style: dashed;
}

button {
  width: 82%;
  padding: 3% 0% 3% 0%;
  margin: 1%;
  background-color: white;
  border-color: darkorange;
  color: darkorange;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: darkorange;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="box" id="div1"></div>
  <div class="box" id="div2"></div>
  <div class="box" id="div3"></div>
  <div class="box" id="div4"></div>
  <div class="box" id="div5"></div>
  <div class="box" id="div6"></div>
  <div class="box" id="div7"></div>
  <div class="box" id="div8"></div>
  <div class="box" id="div9"></div>
  <button id="start">Start flashing</button>
  <button id="stop">Stop</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Tushar, thank you for your answer and suggestion of optimize this code. "getColor should be out of interval loop" is a good suggestion and now I understand how is the execution sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You can't apply the `style` property to a `NodeList` (the result of `document.getElementsByClassName`). Using `setInterval` complicates stopping the color changer, better use `setTimeout` (recursively). Furthermore: ditch `enableBackground`: afaik it's not cross browser compatible.

> I use .sort(function(){return 0.5-Math.random()}) method to get random
>   div(s), but actually it's seems like this is not a completely random.
>   How should I improve the code?

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) on the subject, citing:

> Math.random() does not provide cryptographically secure random
>   numbers. Do not use them for anything related to security. Use the Web
>   Crypto API instead, and more precisely the
>   window.crypto.getRandomValues() method.

To get a number of unique pseudo random values you can use something like:

```
function uniqueRange(rangeLen, maxValue, minValue = 0) {
    let values = [];
    const getValue = () => {
        const current = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxValue - minValue) + minValue);
        return !~values.indexOf(current) ? values.push(current) : getValue();
    };
    while (values.length < rangeLen) {
        getValue();
    }
    return values;
}
```

I rewrote your snippet to demonstrate a way (not necessarily *the* way) to get the result you're after.

```js
(() => {
  const appSetup = {
    stopIt: false,
    nOfRectangles: 3,
    colorDivs: document.querySelector(".main").querySelectorAll("div")
  };
  
  document.querySelector("#stop")
    .addEventListener("click", evt => startStop(evt, true));
  document.querySelector("#start")
    .addEventListener("click", startStop );
  
  function startStop(evt, stop) {
    if (stop) {
      clearTimeout();
      return appSetup.stopIt = true;
    }
    appSetup.stopIt = false;
    return colorChange();
      
  }
  
  function colorChange() {
    const randomColor = () => `rgb(${[
      Math.floor(Math.random() * 256),
      Math.floor(Math.random() * 256),
      Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)
     ].join(", ")})`;
    let i = appSetup.colorDivs.length;
    const uniques = uniqueRange(appSetup.nOfRectangles, i);
    while (i--) {
      appSetup.colorDivs[i].style.backgroundColor = 
        ~uniques.indexOf(i) 
        ? randomColor() 
        : "";
    }
    return appSetup.stopIt ? false : setTimeout(colorChange, 1000);
  }
  
  function uniqueRange(rangeLen, maxValue, minValue = 0) {
    if (rangeLen > maxValue - minValue) {
        throw new RangeError("[rangeLen] can't exceed [maxValue] - [minValue]");
    }
    let values = [];
    const getValue = () => {
        const current = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxValue - minValue) + minValue);
        return !~values.indexOf(current) ? values.push(current) : getValue();
    };
    while (values.length < rangeLen) { getValue(); }
    return values;
  }
})();
```

```css
body {
  font: normal 12px/15px verdana, arial;
}

.colorDiv
{
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 5px;
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: darkorange;
}

.bttns {
  clear: both;
  padding-left: 5px
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="colorDiv"></div>
    <div class="colorDiv"></div>
    <div class="colorDiv"></div>
    <div class="colorDiv"></div>
    <div class="colorDiv"></div>
    <div class="colorDiv"></div>
    <div class="colorDiv"></div>
    <div class="colorDiv"></div>
    <div class="colorDiv"></div>
</div>
<div class="bttns">
    <button id="start">Start</button>
    <button id="stop">Stop</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Kooilnc, thank you for your professional solution sincerely. I notice that you are using ES6 syntax, which is still difficult for me for me to read and understand it, I'll  read your code after I have some more knowledge about ES6 syntax.

Comment: Hi @QingshanShi, no problem. I can advise you to learn ES[6/7/8]. It's not that different and you _will_ do yourself a favor with it.